# Problem inserting bibliography in my research paper

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, texmaker

I am formatting my paper for the **DICTAP 2019** conference submission and for that I had used the Web of Conference `webofc` class. I am facing problem in **inserting bibliography** at the end of paper. The class instruct to use the `bibtex` with `natbib` package. The problem is that my **Texmaker** software gives compilation problem at the end which are:

1. **Error**: Could not open the main tex .aux file
2. **Warnings**: The citations are undefined (It is the case with every citation)

The first error is being skipped when used joint compilation. It gives in bibtex compilation only.

The second are the warnings and the pdf output is having question marks at the reference point.

I am also going to attach the code below:

Main Tex File:

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{webofc}
 \nocite{*}
 \usepackage[varg]{txfonts}   % Web of Conferences font
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{multirow,array}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 %SubFig Package
 %\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
 %\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfon
 %t=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
 %\else
 \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
 %\fi
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.eps}
 %\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf,.png}
 \graphicspath{./Plots,./Plots/Equalization}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \begin{document}{
 \bibliographystyle{woc}
 \bibliography{References} %Imports bibliography file
 %
 \title{Blind Channel Equalization of Star QAM using Dual Dispersion MCMA Algorithm}
 %
 % subtitle is optionnal
 %
 %%%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

 \author{\firstname{Faizan} \lastname{Zaheer}\inst{1}\fnsep\thanks{\email{faizan_zaheer1@yahoo.com}} \and
         \firstname{Sheikh Shahzad} \lastname{Amin}\inst{2}\fnsep\thanks{\email{sheikh.shahzadamin@gmail.com}} 
 }

 \institute{National University of Science and Technology (NUST) 
 \and
 National University of Science and Technology (NUST)}

 \abstract{%
 An algorithm for blind channel equalization is presented for 16 and 32 Star QAM, namely, Dual Dispersion MCMA algorithm. The algorithm taking the concept from MCMA, uses the Dual Dispersion minimization approach for blind channel equalization.  As Star QAM constellation contains two rings, so instead of one, dual dispersion minimization approach is used for its both rings. With modification in MCMA cost function, the new algorithm results in improved performance in convergence rate of Residual ISI and MSE against MCMA algorithm. By incorporating decision directed  approach, the performance increases drastically. Simulation results show effectiveness of proposed algorithm in removing the ISI and correcting the errors in symbols of received signal.
 }
 %
 \maketitle
 %
 %Sections
 \input{Parts/Introduction}
 \input{Parts/Star_QAM}
 \input{Parts/MCMA}
 \input{Parts/Proposed_Algo}
 \input{Parts/Simulations_Results}
 %\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=References]
 \bibliographystyle{woc}
 \bibliography{References} %Imports bibliography file
 }
 \end{document}
```

The Bibliography File:

```
 @article{Godard,
   author        = {Dominique N. Godard},
   title         = {Self-Recovering  Equalization and  Carrier  Tracking in Two-Dimensional  Data  Communication  Systems}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON COMMUNICATIONS},
   volume        = {28},
   number        = {11},
   year          = {November 1980},
   pages         = {1867-1875}
 }

 @article{Sato,
   author        = {Yoichi Sato},
   title         = {A Method of Self-Recovering Equalization for Multilevel Amplitude Modulation Systems}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON COMMUNICATIONS},
   volume        = {23},
   number        = {6},
   year          = {June 1975},
   pages         = {679-682}
 }

 @inproceedings{kilnamoh1,
   author        = {Kil Nam Oh and Yong Ohk Chin},
   title         = {Modified Constant Modulus Algorithm: Blind Equalization and Carrier Phase Recovery Algorithm}",
   eventtitle    = {IEEE International Conference on Communications},
   location      = {Seattle,WA,USA},
   year          = {1995}
 }

 @inproceedings{kilnamoh,
   author        = {Kil Nam Oh and Yong Ohk Chin},
   title         = {New Blind Equalization Techniques based on Constant Modulus Algorithm}",
   eventtitle    = {IEEE Conference on Global Telecommunications},
   location      = {Singapore},
   year          = {1995}
 }


 @article{Yang1,
   author        = {Jian Yang and Jean Jacques Werner and Guy A. Dumont},
   title         = {The Multimodulus Blind Equalization and Its Generalized Algorithms}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE JOURNAL ON SELECTED AREAS IN COMMUNICATIONS},
   volume        = {20},
   number        = {5},
   year          = {June 2002},
   pages         = {997-1015}
 }

 @inproceedings{yang,
   author        = {Jian Yang and Jean Jacques Werner and Guy A. Dumont},
   title         = {THE MULTIMODULUS BLIND EQUALIZATION ALGORITHM}",
   eventtitle    = {13th International Conference on Digital Signal Processing},
   location      = {Santorini, Greece},
   year          = {1997}
 }

 @inproceedings{dutta,
   author        = {Sourjya Dutta and Aniruddha Chandra},
   title         = {Accurate SER Expressions for M-ary Dual Ring Star QAM in Fading Channels}",
   eventtitle    = {2012 International Conference on Communications,Devices and Intelligent Systems (CODIS)",
   location      = {Kolkata,India},
   year          = {2012}
 }

 @article{dutta1,
   author        = {Sourjya Dutta and Iti Saha Misra},
   title         = {Error Analysis of 2-tier M-ary Star QAM Modulation in Shadowed Fading Channels}",
   journaltitle  = {International Journal of Computer Applications},
   volume        = {88},
   number        = {1},
   year          = {February 2014},
   pages         = {}
 }
 @inproceedings{gould,
   author        = {PR Gould and WT Webb and R Steele},
   title         = {Communications to the home via Star QAM}",
   eventtitle    = {IEE Colloquium on Customer Access-the Last 1.6 km},
   location      = {London},
   year          = {1993}

 }

 @article{lucky,
   author        = {R.W. Lucky},
   title         = {Automatic Equalization for Digital Communications}",
   journaltitle  = {The Bell Systems Technical Journal},
   volume        = {44},
   number        = {4},
   year          = {April 1965},
   pages         = {547–588}
 }

 @article{lucky1,
   author        = {R.W. Lucky},
   title         = {Techniques for adaptive equalization of digital communication systems}",
   journaltitle  = {The Bell Systems Technical Journal},
   year          = {February 1966},
   pages         = {255–286}
 }

 @inproceedings{widrow,
   author        = {B. Widrow and M.E. Hoff},
   title         = {Adaptive switching circuits}",
   eventtitle    = {IRE WESCON Convention Record},
   year          = {August 1960},
   pages         = {96–104}

 }

 @inproceedings{kasam,
   author        = {T. Thaiupathump and S.A. Kassam},
   title         = {Square contour algorithm: a new algorithm for blind equalization and carrier phase recovery}",
   eventtitle    = {37th Asilomar Conference on Signals,Systems and Computers},
   location      = {Pacific Grove,CA,USA},
   year          = {November 2003}
 }

 @article{shahzad,
   author        = {Shahzad Amin Sheikh and Pingzhi Fan},
   title         = {New blind equalization techniques based on improved square contour algorithm}",
   journaltitle  = {Institute of Mobile Communications,SWJTU,Chengdu 610031,PR China},
   volume        = {18},
   number        = {5},
   year          = {September 2008},
   pages         = {680-693}
 }

 @article{qasimsara,
   author        = {Qasim Umar Khan and Sara Viqar and  
 Shahzad Amin Sheikh},
   title         = {Two Novel Blind Equalization Algorithms for Rectangular Quadrature Amplitude Modulation Constellations}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Access},
   volume        = {4},
   number        = { },
   year          = {19 December 2016},
   pages         = {9512-9519}
 }

 @article{shafayat,
   author        = {Shafayat Abrar and Ijaz Mansoor Qureshi},
   title         = {Blind Equalization of Cross-QAM Signals}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE SIGNAL PROCESSING LETTERS},
   volume        = {13},
   number        = {12},
   year          = {December 2006},
   pages         = {745-748}
 }

 @patent{godardthirion,
   author        = {Dominique N. Godard and Philippe E. Thirion },
   title         = {Method and device for training an adaptive equalizer by means of an unknown data signal in a quadrature amplitude modulation transmission system}",
   type          = {U.S. Patent},
   number        = {US4227152A},
   year          = {7 October 1980}
 }
 @article{micchida,
   author        = {O. Macchi and E. Eweda},
   title         = {Convergence analysis of self-adaptive equalizers}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
   volume        = {30},
   number        = "",
   year          = {March 1984},
   pages         = {161-176}
 }
 @article{webb,
   author        = {W.T. Webb and R. Steele},
   title         = {Variable rate QAM for mobile radio}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Transactions on Communications},
   volume        = {43},
   number        = {7},
   year          = {July 1995},
   pages         = {2223-2230}
 }
 @inproceedings{gould,
   author        = {P.R. Gould and W.T. Webb and R. Steele},
   title         = {Communications to the home via Star QAM}",
   eventtitle    = {IEE Colloquium on Customer Access - the Last 1.6 km},
   location      = {London, UK},
   year          = {June 1993}
 }
 @article{wuhwang,
   author        = {N. Wu and H. Wang and J. Kuang and C. Yan},
   title         = {Performance Analysis and Optimization of Non-Data-Aided Carrier Frequency Estimator for APSK Signals}",
   journaltitle  = {IEICE TRANSACTIONS on Communications},
   volume        = {E95-B},
   number        = {6},
   year          = {June 2012},
   pages         = {2080-2086}
 }
 @article{picchi,
   author        = {G. Picchi and G. Prati},
   title         = {Blind Equalization and Carrier Recovery Using a {Stop-and-Go{ Decision-Directed Algorithm}",
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Transactions on Communications},
   volume        = {35},
   number        = {9},
   year          = {September 1987},
   pages         = {877-887}
 }
 @inproceedings{shahzad1,
   author        = {Shahzad Amin Sheikh and Pingzhi Fan},
   title         = {Improved Square Contour Algorithm for Blind Equalization of QAM Signals}",
   eventtitle    = {2006 IEEE International Multitopic Conference},
   location      = {Islamabad, Pakistan},
   year          = {December 2006}
 }
 @article{kassam1,
 author        = {T. Thaiupathump and L. He and S.A. Kassam},
 title         = {Square contour algorithm for blind equalization of QAM signals}",
 journaltitle  = {in Signal Processing on Elsevier},
 eventtitle    = "",
 location      = "",
 volume        = {86},
 number        = {11},
 year          = {February 2006},
 doi              = {10.1016/j.sigpro.2006.02.035}
 }
```

Please help me as I have to submit the format for camera ready submission next week. Thank you.

Comment: We do not have your `\input`ed file. Delete that code and add an short exampe code showing how you cite one or two entries of the bib file. Is your class a standard class? Do you have a link to it? I can not see that you are loading `natbib` in your preamble ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have a lot of errors in it.

Let me name some of them:

1. You can not use `\nocite{*}` in the preamble. Move it into the document (somewhere after `\begin{document}`.
2. If you want the bibliography at the **end** of document do not use the commands at the **beginning** (I only commented them in the following corrected MWE, marked important code changes in the tex code with `<===========`): 
   `%\bibliographystyle{woc} % <====================================== ?????` and `%\bibliography{References}`.
3. Do not call `\bibliographystyle{woc}` twice, it is already done in your used class and each new call throws an error.
4. you have two bib entries called `gould`. That is not allowed. Check if they are double, then delete one or rename the second to `goulda`.
5. All your titles end with `}",` delete the `"` in each title at the end of the line in your `bib` file.
6. One title has two more `{` in the title text, add the two missing `}}` at the end of line.
7. Some entries use an real emdash instead `--`. Simply change all (correct or wrong) `-` in your page fields to `--`.
8. I simply commented your commands `\input{...}` because we do not have this files ...
9. Please check the error messages and warnings you got in your `*.log` and `*.blg` file. Correct all of them!

The following code uses package `filecontents` to have `bib` and `tex` file in one compilable MWE. That is only useful for my MWE, please do not use it in real documents!):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{Godard,
   author        = {Dominique N. Godard},
   title         = {Self-Recovering  Equalization and  Carrier  Tracking in Two-Dimensional  Data  Communication  Systems},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON COMMUNICATIONS},
   volume        = {28},
   number        = {11},
   year          = {November 1980},
   pages         = {1867-1875}
 }

 @article{Sato,
   author        = {Yoichi Sato},
   title         = {A Method of Self-Recovering Equalization for Multilevel Amplitude Modulation Systems},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON COMMUNICATIONS},
   volume        = {23},
   number        = {6},
   year          = {June 1975},
   pages         = {679-682}
 }

 @inproceedings{kilnamoh1,
   author        = {Kil Nam Oh and Yong Ohk Chin},
   title         = {Modified Constant Modulus Algorithm: Blind Equalization and Carrier Phase Recovery Algorithm},
   eventtitle    = {IEEE International Conference on Communications},
   location      = {Seattle,WA,USA},
   year          = {1995}
 }

 @inproceedings{kilnamoh,
   author        = {Kil Nam Oh and Yong Ohk Chin},
   title         = {New Blind Equalization Techniques based on Constant Modulus Algorithm},
   eventtitle    = {IEEE Conference on Global Telecommunications},
   location      = {Singapore},
   year          = {1995}
 }


 @article{Yang1,
   author        = {Jian Yang and Jean Jacques Werner and Guy A. Dumont},
   title         = {The Multimodulus Blind Equalization and Its Generalized Algorithms},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE JOURNAL ON SELECTED AREAS IN COMMUNICATIONS},
   volume        = {20},
   number        = {5},
   year          = {June 2002},
   pages         = {997-1015}
 }

 @inproceedings{yang,
   author        = {Jian Yang and Jean Jacques Werner and Guy A. Dumont},
   title         = {THE MULTIMODULUS BLIND EQUALIZATION ALGORITHM},
   eventtitle    = {13th International Conference on Digital Signal Processing},
   location      = {Santorini, Greece},
   year          = {1997}
 }

 @inproceedings{dutta,
   author        = {Sourjya Dutta and Aniruddha Chandra},
   title         = {Accurate SER Expressions for M-ary Dual Ring Star QAM in Fading Channels},
   eventtitle    = {2012 International Conference on Communications,Devices and Intelligent Systems (CODIS)},
   location      = {Kolkata,India},
   year          = {2012}
 }

 @article{dutta1,
   author        = {Sourjya Dutta and Iti Saha Misra},
   title         = {Error Analysis of 2-tier M-ary Star QAM Modulation in Shadowed Fading Channels},
   journaltitle  = {International Journal of Computer Applications},
   volume        = {88},
   number        = {1},
   year          = {February 2014},
   pages         = {}
 }
 @inproceedings{gould,
   author        = {PR Gould and WT Webb and R Steele},
   title         = {Communications to the home via Star QAM},
   eventtitle    = {IEE Colloquium on Customer Access-the Last 1.6 km},
   location      = {London},
   year          = {1993}

 }

 @article{lucky,
   author        = {R.W. Lucky},
   title         = {Automatic Equalization for Digital Communications},
   journaltitle  = {The Bell Systems Technical Journal},
   volume        = {44},
   number        = {4},
   year          = {April 1965},
   pages         = {547–588}
 }

 @article{lucky1,
   author        = {R.W. Lucky},
   title         = {Techniques for adaptive equalization of digital communication systems},
   journaltitle  = {The Bell Systems Technical Journal},
   year          = {February 1966},
   pages         = {255–286}
 }

 @inproceedings{widrow,
   author        = {B. Widrow and M.E. Hoff},
   title         = {Adaptive switching circuits},
   eventtitle    = {IRE WESCON Convention Record},
   year          = {August 1960},
   pages         = {96--104}

 }

 @inproceedings{kasam,
   author        = {T. Thaiupathump and S.A. Kassam},
   title         = {Square contour algorithm: a new algorithm for blind equalization and carrier phase recovery},
   eventtitle    = {37th Asilomar Conference on Signals,Systems and Computers},
   location      = {Pacific Grove,CA,USA},
   year          = {November 2003}
 }

 @article{shahzad,
   author        = {Shahzad Amin Sheikh and Pingzhi Fan},
   title         = {New blind equalization techniques based on improved square contour algorithm},
   journaltitle  = {Institute of Mobile Communications,SWJTU,Chengdu 610031,PR China},
   volume        = {18},
   number        = {5},
   year          = {September 2008},
   pages         = {680-693}
 }

 @article{qasimsara,
   author        = {Qasim Umar Khan and Sara Viqar and  
 Shahzad Amin Sheikh},
   title         = {Two Novel Blind Equalization Algorithms for Rectangular Quadrature Amplitude Modulation Constellations},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Access},
   volume        = {4},
   number        = { },
   year          = {19 December 2016},
   pages         = {9512-9519}
 }

 @article{shafayat,
   author        = {Shafayat Abrar and Ijaz Mansoor Qureshi},
   title         = {Blind Equalization of Cross-QAM Signals},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE SIGNAL PROCESSING LETTERS},
   volume        = {13},
   number        = {12},
   year          = {December 2006},
   pages         = {745-748}
 }

 @patent{godardthirion,
   author        = {Dominique N. Godard and Philippe E. Thirion },
   title         = {Method and device for training an adaptive equalizer by means of an unknown data signal in a quadrature amplitude modulation transmission system},
   type          = {U.S. Patent},
   number        = {US4227152A},
   year          = {7 October 1980}
 }
 @article{micchida,
   author        = {O. Macchi and E. Eweda},
   title         = {Convergence analysis of self-adaptive equalizers},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
   volume        = {30},
   number        = "",
   year          = {March 1984},
   pages         = {161-176}
 }
 @article{webb,
   author        = {W.T. Webb and R. Steele},
   title         = {Variable rate QAM for mobile radio},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Transactions on Communications},
   volume        = {43},
   number        = {7},
   year          = {July 1995},
   pages         = {2223-2230}
 }
 @inproceedings{goulda,
   author        = {P.R. Gould and W.T. Webb and R. Steele},
   title         = {Communications to the home via Star QAM},
   eventtitle    = {IEE Colloquium on Customer Access - the Last 1.6 km},
   location      = {London, UK},
   year          = {June 1993}
 }
 @article{wuhwang,
   author        = {N. Wu and H. Wang and J. Kuang and C. Yan},
   title         = {Performance Analysis and Optimization of Non-Data-Aided Carrier Frequency Estimator for APSK Signals},
   journaltitle  = {IEICE TRANSACTIONS on Communications},
   volume        = {E95-B},
   number        = {6},
   year          = {June 2012},
   pages         = {2080--2086}
 }
 @article{picchi,
   author        = {G. Picchi and G. Prati},
   title         = {Blind Equalization and Carrier Recovery Using a {Stop-and-Go{ Decision-Directed Algorithm}}},
   journaltitle  = {IEEE Transactions on Communications},
   volume        = {35},
   number        = {9},
   year          = {September 1987},
   pages         = {877--887}
 }
 @inproceedings{shahzad1,
   author        = {Shahzad Amin Sheikh and Pingzhi Fan},
   title         = {Improved Square Contour Algorithm for Blind Equalization of QAM Signals},
   eventtitle    = {2006 IEEE International Multitopic Conference},
   location      = {Islamabad, Pakistan},
   year          = {December 2006}
 }
 @article{kassam1,
 author        = {T. Thaiupathump and L. He and S.A. Kassam},
 title         = {Square contour algorithm for blind equalization of QAM signals},
 journaltitle  = {in Signal Processing on Elsevier},
 eventtitle    = "",
 location      = "",
 volume        = {86},
 number        = {11},
 year          = {February 2006},
 doi              = {10.1016/j.sigpro.2006.02.035}
 }
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[twocolumn]{webofc}

 \usepackage[varg]{txfonts}   % Web of Conferences font
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{multirow,array}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 %SubFig Package
 %\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
 %\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfon
 %t=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
 %\else
 \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
 %\fi
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.eps}
 %\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf,.png}
 \graphicspath{./Plots,./Plots/Equalization}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*} % <==========================================================
%\bibliographystyle{woc} % <====================================== ?????
%\bibliography{References} %Imports bibliography file References.bib <============= ?????
 %
 \title{Blind Channel Equalization of Star QAM using Dual Dispersion MCMA Algorithm}
 %
 % subtitle is optionnal
 %
 %%%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

 \author{\firstname{Faizan} \lastname{Zaheer}\inst{1}\fnsep\thanks{\email{faizan_zaheer1@yahoo.com}} \and
         \firstname{Sheikh Shahzad} \lastname{Amin}\inst{2}\fnsep\thanks{\email{sheikh.shahzadamin@gmail.com}} 
 }

 \institute{National University of Science and Technology (NUST) 
 \and
 National University of Science and Technology (NUST)}

\abstract{%
 An algorithm for blind channel equalization is presented for 16 and 32 Star QAM, namely, Dual Dispersion MCMA algorithm. The algorithm taking the concept from MCMA, uses the Dual Dispersion minimization approach for blind channel equalization.  As Star QAM constellation contains two rings, so instead of one, dual dispersion minimization approach is used for its both rings. With modification in MCMA cost function, the new algorithm results in improved performance in convergence rate of Residual ISI and MSE against MCMA algorithm. By incorporating decision directed  approach, the performance increases drastically. Simulation results show effectiveness of proposed algorithm in removing the ISI and correcting the errors in symbols of received signal.
}
 %
\maketitle
 %
 %Sections
 %\input{Parts/Introduction}
 %\input{Parts/Star_QAM}
 %\input{Parts/MCMA}
 %\input{Parts/Proposed_Algo}
 %\input{Parts/Simulations_Results}
 %\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=References]
%\bibliographystyle{woc} % <============================================
 \bibliography{References} %Imports bibliography file References.bib

 \end{document}
```

resulting in the following page:

[image: resulting pdf page]

Comment: Okay I will check your points soon

Comment: No I have tried it with only one reference and minimal tex file, the result is same it skips the bibliography and gives warning of citation undefined.

Comment: I am using bibtex.exe in BibLatex command section of Texmaker settings.

Comment: The bibtex compilation gives error of **I couldn't open file name `build\Paper.aux**

Comment: Thanks all. The problem is solved in Texstudio somehow